# Passing a single object from a JSON file

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm probably stuck on something basic but I just can't wrap my head around it.

I have a service that passes data to my components data.service.ts

```
  export class DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTrailers() {
    return this.http.get('./assets/trailers.json')
  }

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
  }


  getUser(userId) {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + userId)
  }


  getTrailer(trailerID) {
    return this.http.get('./assets/trailers.json/' + trailerID)
  }
}
```

But I'm having issues with sending the correct data in the `getTrailer` method.
Since obviously my latest "attempt" will try to find `trailers.json/1` which doesn't exist.

The only idea I have right now, that should work is to use brute force to mimic the structure of

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
```

by making tons of trailersX.json files

I also tried console logging

```
getTrailers() {
    return this.http.get('./assets/trailers.json')
  }
```

to see what if I can work with that but all I get is an undefined object.

Comment: I don't see how the title of your question (about array iteration) relates to your question (about URLs and ajax).

Comment: Yeah my bad, thanks

Comment: here is a working example loading json (ng 5) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-local-json-sbfitz?file=app%2Fjson-service.ts

Comment: thanks but that not quite it, that pretty much made the whole file into a string... But what I want is to take 1 object out of the array in the file and pass it as data

Comment: you want something like trailers.json/1? if so, you might have to implement your own router

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this by using rxjs map operator

```
getTrailer(trailerID) {
  return this.http.get('./assets/trailers.json')
    .pipe(map(trailers => {

       return trailers.filter(t => t.id === trailerID)
    }));
}
```

If you are using angular 5 use below

```
getTrailer(trailerID) {
  return this.http.get('./assets/trailers.json')
    map(trailers => {

       return trailers.filter(t => t.id === trailerID)
    });
}
```

Checkout this working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-local-json-ptsnrv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)